# Is there a way to inject final class with guice?

Tags: java, email, guice, final

I have provider which should inject javax.mail.Session (provider looks it up in env. context of tomcat) as singleton. There is a problem when I use field injection somewhere in code:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class javax.mail.Session
```

Is there a way to go round this? Only clues that I've found point to Spring AOP/Proxies.

Thanks && regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP. It seems that there is some limitations:

> Limitations
>
> Behind the scenes, method interception is implemented by generating
>   bytecode at runtime. Guice dynamically creates a subclass that applies
>   interceptors by overriding methods. If you are on a platform that
>   doesn't support bytecode generation (such as Android), you  should use
>   Guice without AOP support.
>
> This approach imposes limits on what classes and methods can be
>   intercepted:
>
> Classes must be public or package-private. Classes must be non-final
>   Methods must be public, package-private or protected Methods must be
>   non-final Instances must be created by Guice by an `@Inject`-annotated
>   or no-argument constructor